# Can any glider incapable of powered flight strike its prey by descending on it?

Tags: flight

### TLDR

I was not able to find the precise definitions of “**true flight**“, “sustained flight“ and “**gliding**“, that are often used on Wikipedia.  My layman’s understanding is that true flight is the same as “**powered flight**” and means the animal can utilise muscles to generate life force that exceeds its weight under a wide range of air flow conditions. That is, it does not need upward air currents such as thermals

By contrast, **gliding** is defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_and_gliding_animals#Powered_flight) as:

> falling at an angle less than 45° from the horizontal with lift from adapted aerofoil membranes

You are welcome to suggest more correct definitions.

### Question

Can any animal that glides but is incapable of true flight (of course hawks may glide) descend upon its prey?

I am aware of this question not being very well defined, since animals such as sugar gliders can jump on their prey and  perhaps utilise a tiny amount of lift to prolong their jump. It is difficult to rigorously separate this from gliding. Let’s require that the animal glides a distance more than 10 times its length from a height more than 10 times its height.

### Inconclusive information

**Bats**

Don’t count because they are capable of powered flight. But [they can do it.](https://youtu.be/wgLHUNBWR58)

**Sugar gliders**

Can “*leap out to catch flying insects*“ ([source](https://www.activewild.com/sugar-glider-facts/)), but that’s all I found.

**Flying squirrels**

“*harvest fruits, nuts, fungi, and birds' eggs*”([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_squirrel#Diet)), so they may not even prey.

**Colugos**

Appear to be strictly vegetarian ([source](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesengleiter)).

Comment: Sure, but it would be very situational. True flight = powered flight = sustained flight (although an albatross soaring the waves indefinitely could be technically be sustained but does not follow the spirit of the term).